# Объединение строк в ячейке в офисе (ворде или врайтер)

Tags: wildcards

Работаю часто на Writer из-за того что приходят документы в формате word, в каждой колонке несколько строк может быть, могут быть переносы в строках либо новые абзацы либо просто перенос строки, либо 1 или несколько переносов. В регулярных мало разбираюсь, только подсказали следующие команды:

1. найди **\n** заменить на **пробел** (вроде как должен удалить переносы строки и поставить пробел
2. найти **^(.*)$** заменить **!$0!** (в начале и в конце строки ставит восклицательные знаки - это нормально работает)
3. найти **пробелы** и заменить их на **?** (из шага 1)

Другой вариант (для другого стобца)

1. Найти **$** заменить на **\t** (ищет пробелы и заменяет табулятором - работает не всегда)

И еще один вариант

1. Найти **^(.*)$** заменить на **!$0!** (в случае если строки друг за другом идут в ячейкЕ, то все нормально, ставит восклицательные знаки
2. найти **$** заменить на **""** (пусто) (не получается в open office writer) поставить "пусто", он думает что на пробел надо заменить либо не находит таких строк

Скрин того как нужно заменять http://prntscr.com/utz651

Comment: Скрин вставьте картинкой, а не по ссылке, а лучше приведите примеры текстов и что в них найти/поменять в соответствии с [описанием метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/регулярные-выражения/info)

Answer (score 0):

В MS Word:

Поиск: `^p`

Замена: {ничего}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если заменять надо только в одной таблице или одном фрагменте, а не во всём файле - выделить таблицу/фрагмент, когда предложит продолжить в оставшейся части документа - отказаться. Если в нескольких фрагментах - обработать по одному.